# failed to use some application on windows wsl

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got some problem as I using Ubuntu as a subsystem in Win10.
For example, when I use 'python' as most of other applications in Windows command, it work, but in wsl, it dosen't work.It turns out that I have to use 'python.exe' to start it. But I found I can use 'curl' correctly without '.exe'. I check the environment variable in wsl, it is correct. I also found that the 'curl' is not what I install in D disk. I have try to reinstall my application in C disk, but it doesn't work neither.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3fDY.png)

Answer (score 1):

`python` would run the Python that is installed on Linux, `python.exe` would run the Python that is installed on Windows (if it's in the `PATH`).

Probably you didn't install Python on your Linux yet... You can install it using `sudo apt install python3`

(`curl` is installed by default, `which curl` will show you that it runs it from `/usr/bin/curl`)

Comment: But I am pretty sure that I can use like what I said before. For example, like python, golang, nodejs, as I install wsl on my PC, I can use these command immediately. I got this question just now because I just reset my PC for some reason.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, your WSL environment is like its own separate OS, just with a bit of interoperability such as the option to  directly execute Windows programs. But the filename is different (for example `python` vs `python.exe`) so you deliberately need to run Windows applications this way if you really want to. It's better this way anyway because they are still running in Windows and don't know about Linux, so if you or some other Linux application would run Windows' Python from Linux by accident, things would mysteriously break because for example the path formats are different.

Comment: Maybe you previously had one of those hacks installed that allowed you to run a few things as if they were installed on Linux even though they are actually in Windows, but that's a bad idea for the reason I explained above. You should install those tools that you need on Linux separately from those that you use in Windows.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Actually running .exe from WSL is quite common. I do recommend running python on Linux side but if you need to run it from Windows, you'll want to use `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the interop section which includes  `appendWindowsPath=true`

Comment: Yes of course, my point was just that replacing Linux' python with Windows' python.exe, especially transparently, is a bad idea because it's not quite the same.